# Is there any evidence that there are more Palaces than the ones visited in Persona 5's main story?

Tags: persona-5, persona-5-royal

Before anything : I'll try to limit spoilers as much as possible, but some elements of this question might still qualify as minor spoilers. Read at your own risks.

After getting back to Persona 5 through the port of Royal on PC, I've been looking at many aspects of the game's lore and universe that I missed during my original playthrough. In particular, I've been looking at Palaces.

A simple thought came to mind : it seems weird that the story would bring the main character to all Palaces over the course of a single year. It seems like quite the coincidence, when you think about the different rulers and how seemingly random their encounters have been.

Thinking it over, this observation refined into the following thought : what tells us that we visit all Palaces? Because of this, I've been looking at whether or not we have any clues or evidence that there are, or could be, other Palaces we never visit during the course of the story.

I couldn't find any conclusive dialogue or other clues regarding this question, which is why I'm now asking it here :

**In Persona 5 (and Persona 5 Royal), is there any evidence regarding whether or not other Palaces exist, or whether there could be other Palaces that are never visited?**

I am looking for answers backed by **actual official sources**, be it from in-game dialogue, any sort of codex or other form of "canon" information. Baseless, opinion-based speculation will be disregarded.

Comment: The game describes the palaces as the representation of an individual's distorted view of the world, like how Kamoshida views the school as his castle, or Kaneshiro views Shibuya as his bank. We even have Mementos as the palace of the masses, belonging to all the people whose distortion is not strong enough to produce their own palace. Therefore I believe that there are countless more palaces that the Phantom Thieves never got to visit.

Comment: @Nolonar I believe so as well. What I'm looking for is if it's ever stated explicitely or confirmed (or denied) in some way. Without that it's really left ambiguous more than anything.

Comment: @Matthieu There are some conversations towards the end of the game that (possibly) allude to this (so spoilers below this point a bit...) after the last palace of the non-Royal content, after the palace leader is defeated, there are conversations between his lackeys that allude to his aspirations of using the metaverse for his continued political aspirations, and how they can continue that legacy forward. However, even with those conversations, it never directly concludes this means other palaces (vs. something more generally speaking like Mementos).